# applicationWillResignActive == CRASH

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Game, Sprite Kit, a problem with incoming calls, ect:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
var pauseBool = true
...............
func pauseGame(){
    self.scene?.view?.isPaused = true       
}

func playGame(){
    self.scene?.view?.isPaused = false
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
         let location = touch.location(in: self)
          if pauseButton.contains(location) {
                if pauseBool {
                    pauseGame()
                    pauseBool = false
                } else {
                    playGame()
                    pauseBool = true
                }
   }
}
.............
extension GameScene {
func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    playGame()
}

func applicationWillResignActive() {
    pauseGame()
}
```

If press PauseButton = everything works perfectly! Always!
If an incoming phone call or SMS message or HomeButton = 50/50 CRASH!
Thank you!

Comment: Try adding some delay after pauseGame() in applicationWillResignActive()

Comment: @aBilal17 for example ?

Comment: Add this line Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.0) and then try

Comment: crash again( delay in applicationWillResignActive?

Comment: Never call `Thread.sleep` on a main thread,  how about you post what the actual crash is and provide more information

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Can you please tell me what additional information is needed?

Comment: ... how can I tell you? It is your problem

Answer (score 0):

A solution is found! In my case there was a conflict in playing sounds in the game.

Instead:

```
run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Wow", waitForCompletion: false))
```

Used:

```
func allShortSound(name: String) {
    if let shortSound = childNode(withName:
        "shortSound") {
        shortSound.removeFromParent()
    }
    let shortSnd = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: name)
    shortSnd.name = "shortSound"
    shortSnd.autoplayLooped = false
    addChild(shortSnd)
    shortSnd.run(SKAction.play())
}
```

Then in the right place we call this function

```
allShortSound(name: "Wow")
```

Now everything works perfectly!

Ta!